# Commandline to modify tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, msbuild, oracleclient, tnsnames

Is there a command line utility to modify the tnsnames.ora file for the oracle client?

[EDIT] I'm looking for something similar to odbcconf.exe (for editing ODBC connection on windows) to modify the tnsnames.ora file.

[EDIT2] I'm using MSBUILD from my automated build script.  The [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) has an AddTnsName task that fits exactly what I need.  My googling skillz must be weak.  I should have been searching for MSBuild and tnsnames.ora instead of command line tnsnames.ora.  However, it does surprise me that Oracle does not supply a command line utility like odbcconf for tnsnames.ora.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add a new registration or modify an existing one from an automated build script.

Comment: any sample code using MsBuild ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, this file is best maintained with an editor, but there is a Net Configuration Assistant GUI that will lead you through the steps to create one.

[Edit]
I see from your additional comments now that you're looking for a scriptable way to add entries, and the direct answer to your question is no, there's no Oracle utility to do this.  You'll have to come up with some cat|sed|awk solution on your own.

Answer (score 5):

You can provide the whole `TNS` string as the connection parameter:

```
sqlplus "scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICE)))"
```

Alternatively, if your client supports `EasyConnect` syntax, you can go just this:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@//127.0.0.1/MYSERVICE
```

Answer (score 2):

vi?
notepad?
um ...